# How to use object destructuring spread operator to delete multiple object properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using in my reducers Map/Associative array to store object via string ID.

When I need new item into Map I am using this construction

```
rows: { ...state.rows, [row.id]: row }
```

When I need delete item form map by Id I am using this.

```
const  { [rowId]: deleted, ...rows } = state.rows;
```

Than in variable rows I have map and property with name `rowId` is missing.

I am wondering how can i do this if i have multiple Ids in array and I need delete all of them via `...` operator and destructuring.

```
const contentIds = ['id1','id2','id3']

// something like ???
const {...[ids], ...rows}
```

Yes I can write lamda for that or use omit lodash. 
But just interesting if it is possible.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wander how can i do this if i have multiple Ids in array and I
>   need delete all of them via `...` operator and destructuring.

No you can't do this, you're probably getting confused with `rest` and `spread` syntax, `...` on the left hand side of assignment is `rest` syntax not `spread`

[**Rest and Spread**](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-object-rest-spread/)

And `rest` syntax expects `...` followed by variable name, what you're trying is [**syntaxError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/No_variable_name)

```js
const object = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
const a = ['a','b']
const {...[a], ...rows} = object

console.log(rows)
```

More over you can't use `,` tralling comma after `rest` so even if you do

```
let {...a, ...rows } = obj
```

it's still invalid

```js
const object = {a:1,b:2,c:3}

const {...a, ...rows} = object

console.log(rows)
```

You can use the solution suggested by [**@nina**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743411/9624435) or you can create a copy of object and loop through `contentIds` and delete key/value from copyObj to get desired value

```js
const object = { id: 1, id1: 2, id2: 3 };
const contentIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
const objCopy = object

contentIds.forEach(key=>{
  delete objCopy[key]
})

console.log(objCopy);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the keys with the object.

```js
var object = { id: 1, id1: 2, id2: 3 },
    contentIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
    result = contentIds.reduce((o, k) => ({ [k]: _, ...r } = o, r), object);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi ... like your solution ... I know how to do it ... I was just wonder if it is possible do it via simple spread and destructuring as elegant  way as  deleting one id

Comment: the answer is, you can not spread the keys for getting an assignment. actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myObj = { id1: 'test', id2: 'test', id3: 'test' }
const idsToFilter = ['id1', 'id2']
const { id1, id2, ...filtered } = myObj
console.log(filtered)
```

However you can't do that programmatically unless you know the exact ids you want to filter from the object however. if you want to do it based on an array of ids instead, you'd need to use something like this

```js
function filterObjectByKeys (object, keysToFilter) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((accum, key) => {
    if (!keysToFilter.includes(key)) {
      return { ...accum, [key]: object[key] }
    } else {
      return accum
    }
  }, {})
}
```